# What should I change to make any random generated number positive or negative?

Tags: java

Right now, it makes number above 50 positive and numbers below 50 negative. How should I change the code to make it so that any number can be either positive or negative?

```
public class P1G
{
    static void main()
    {
        int[] a = new int[10];
        for(int index = 0; index < 10; index ++)
        {
            double r = Math.random();
            int p = (int) (((100 - 0) + 1) * r + 0); // (-) or (+)
            if ( p < 50 )
            {
                int n = (int) (((100 - 0) + 1) * r + 0);
                n = n * -1;
                System.out.println(n);
            }
            else
            {
                int n = (int) (((100 - 0) + 1) * r + 0);
                n = n;
                System.out.println(n);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you write this code? If you had written it and knew how to make it positive in some cases and negative in others, you should be able to figure out the answer to your question...something smells fishy. Are you sure this isn't homework?

Comment: @KevinL Math.random() gives you a positive number. Now how do you want to decide whether to print a positive or negative number?

Comment: I specifically love the ((100 - 0) + 1), that is duplicated 3 times - surely this could be set as a constant. ;-)

Comment: Three word answer - scaling and translation.  (Simple maths.)

Comment: Err, change the *sign?* What's the question here?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something you want

```
int n = (int) (Math.random() * 101) - 50;
System.out.println(n);
```

**Explanation**

Get a random `int` in the range 0 to 100 and subtract 50, that gives the range -50 to positive 50. Per the [`Math.random()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) Javadoc -

> Returns a `double` value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use this?

```
new Random().nextInt(50)-100
```

Oh, sorry,, make a big careless mistake.

```
new Random().nextInt(100) - 50
```

Comment: I am not sure i get his meaning,, he want the range from -50 to 50 right?

Comment: No you can't - this will give a value between -100 and -50. Other answer have this correct.

Comment: Sorry,, answer it too fast and making mistake :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of randoming over `[0,101]`, you can random over `[-50, 50]` by doing the following:

```
int p = (int) (100  * r - 50);
```